# What does the ^ operator in python do to integers?

Tags: python, operators

I know it´s the XOR for statements, but what does 2^2 compute in python?
If i give

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
[x^2 for x in list]
```

it computes to

```
[3, 0, 1, 6, 7, 4, 5, 10]
```

Comment: It's still just a bitwise XOR.

Comment: You answered your own question. It is XOR. I'm not sure what you mean by "XOR for statements"

Comment: x is still an operand, and `^` is still an operator, regardless of where it is.

Comment: Are you asking how exactly the XOR value is computed?

Answer (score 3):

It's a bitwise XOR.
You are doing a bit-by-bit XOR with 2 to all of your values in the list.
For example the first element is 1^2 = 3.
Why? 1 is `01` in binary, 2 is `10` and so: (I'm omitting leading zeroes)

```
      01
XOR   10
=     11
```

It gives 3 since `11` is 3 in binary.

Answer (score 0):

^ is the Bitwise XOR operator in python. So in your example it return the bitwise XOR of each number in your list with 2. In that way I think it now makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

^ is used for an exclusive-or (bitwise) operation.

Make sure the power is integer only.